# use Drag and drop file as /f findstr

Tags: batch-file, drag-and-drop, dos, findstr

Im trying to write a script where users can drag and drop a *.txt or blank extension file for the
/F file list search string any suggestions?

This is all that I have so far.

```
@echo off 
for /F %%i in (*.) do (
  echo searching for %%i 
  Findstr  /s /I /n   "%%i" *.txt >>\\myourput.csv
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for /F %%i in (%*) do (
```

`%*` stands for "all parameters" (if you drag one or more files to the batchfile, the batchfile will run with those file(s) as parameters)

Use `%1` to use the first parameter only.